# Does the exceptional Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}_2$ arise from the isometry group of any projective space?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, quaternions, projective-space, octonions

I learned from [Baez's notes on octonions](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/octonions/oct.pdf) that the classical simple Lie algebras can be identified with the Lie algebras of isometry groups of projective spaces over $\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{H}$, and that there is a way to generalize this for the exceptional algebras $\mathfrak{f}_4, \mathfrak{e}_6, \mathfrak{e}_7$ and $\mathfrak{e}_8$ as isometry groups of "projective planes" over the octonions $\mathbb{O}$ (the Cayley plane), bioctonions $\mathbb{C} \otimes \mathbb{O}$, quateroctonions $\mathbb{H} \otimes \mathbb{O}$ and octooctonions $\mathbb{O} \otimes \mathbb{O}$ respectively, which leads to the Magic Square construction.

The exceptional algebra $\mathfrak{g}_2$, on the other hand, is characterized as the algebra of derivations of the octonions. Why isn't there a projective space corresponding to it, like for the other simple Lie algebras? Or is there?

---

**Edit:** here's some new information that may help in answering the question.

- I've found that there exists an extension of the magic square construction, called the magic triangle (Deligne, 1996), which does include $\mathfrak{g}_2$. However, the column in which it appears corresponds to a "dimension" $2\nu - 2$ of $-2/3$, so if we were to extend the projective plane interpretation we would have

  $$\mathfrak{g}_2 = \mathfrak{isom}((\mathbb{A} \otimes \mathbb{O})\mathbb{P}^2)$$

  where $\mathbb{A}$ would be a division algebra (superalgebra?) over $\mathbb{R}$ of dimension $-2/3$. I haven't heard of vector spaces with negative fractional dimension, but perhaps there is a way to make sense out of this.
- Someone has pointed me to the classification of symmetric spaces https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_space#Classification_result of compact type, which include all the "classical" projective spaces as special cases of real (**BDI**), complex (**AIII**) and quaternionic (**CII**) Grassmanians, and also the exceptional Cayley and Rosenfeld projective planes (**FII**, **EIII**, **EVI** and **EVIII**) mentioned above.

  The last space **G**, related to the group $G_2$, is the "space of subalgebras of the octonion algebra $\mathbb{O}$ which are isomorphic to the quaternion algebra $\mathbb{H}$". But there's no mention of it being a  projective space. Could this be what I'm looking for?

Comment: @DietrichBurde But the Fano plane only contains the unit imaginary octonions, no? And the automorphism group of the Fano plane itself is the discrete group PGL(3,2).

Comment: I mean the other automorphism group, i.e., $Aut(\mathbb{O})=G_2$, and $\mathbb{O}$ is "represented" in $\mathbb{F}_2\mathbb{P}^2$.

Comment: For the construction of $\mathbb{O}$ using the Fano plane, see section $2$ [here](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/octonions/oct.pdf).

Comment: @DietrichBurde Still, I think that doesn't answer my question. The construction I'm referring to in my post is precisely in section $4$ of the paper you linked. It identifies, for example, the algebra of isometries $\mathfrak{isom}(\mathbb{RP}^n)$ with $\mathfrak{so}(n+1)$ and $\mathfrak{isom}(\mathbb{OP}^2)$ with $\mathfrak{f}_4$. My question is whether there is a projective space $X$ such that $\mathfrak{isom}(X) \cong \mathfrak{g}_2$.

Comment: Baez says that only $4$ exceptional Lie algebras come from the isometry groups of the projective planes related to octonions, but $G_2$ does not (page $3$ of your link). He continues, that on the other hand, $G_2$ arises directly as automorphism group of the octonions. I do not know why there is no projective space corresponding to it.